# How disable linux console on serial port

Tags: console, serial-port, embedded-linux

I'm using an embedded system with yocto (hardknott) with 2 RS232 port :

```
     /dev/ttymxc0  
     /dev/ttymxc1
```

both used as console with a login prompt. Now I would switch one of that (e.g /dev/ttymxc0)  and use it as  normal serial, the reason to do that is permit the serial comunication between two device

How can do that via C code or via shell command?

I tryed with

```
systemctl stop serial-getty@ttymxc0.service
```

and

```
systemctl stop serial-getty@ttymxc0.service
systemctl disable serial-getty@ttyS0.service
```

but I'm not able to change the port behaviour

Comment: Your use of terminology is sloppy, so your question is ambiguous.  "*I'm using ... with 2 RS232 port : /dev/ttymxc0  /dev/ttymxc1*" -- No, those are just two *serial terminals*.  Instead of RS-232, there could be RS-485 transceivers or no transceivers, just TTL levels.  "*both used as console with a login prompt*" -- A Linux *console* is a terminal that displays kernel messages.  You may or may not be able to login at this console.  You seem to be conflating *console* and a login terminal.  The designation of a *console* is completely independent of the login capability of a terminal.

Comment: "*I tryed [sic] with ... but I'm not able to change the port behaviour*" -- Instead of a negative description, state what does happen (i.e. only what you actually observe), and why that is a problem.  And it's not a port, but a serial terminal.  That's why the device name begins with "tty...".

Comment: @sawdust thanks a lot! The post indicated works for me